# How to define a finitely presented group in GAP

Tags: group-theory, group-presentation, gap, combinatorial-group-theory, frattini-subgroup

In the Group $G=\langle a,b: a^{16}=1 , b^4=a^8 , [a,b]=a^{-2} \rangle$ , the center and the Frattini subgroups are cyclic. I would like to show this fact by using GAP. How I can define this group by GAP?

Answer (score 2):

You can take a look at the documentation where this is described very thoroughly:
https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap47.html

Applied to your example we get:

```
gap> H := FreeGroup( "a", "b" );
<free group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> G := H / [H.1^16, H.2^4*H.1^(-8), H.1*H.2*H.1^(-1)*H.2^(-1)*H.1^2];
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
gap> G2 := H / [[H.1^16, H.1^0], [H.2^4, H.1^8], [H.1*H.2*H.1^(-1)*H.2^(-1), H.1^(-2)]];
<fp group on the generators [ a, b ]>
```

So we have defined your group $G$ on the generators $a,b$ in two different ways, once with the relators and once with the equations.

You can now easily find a description of the center or the Frattini subgroup:

```
gap> StructureDescription(Center(G));
"C2"
gap> StructureDescription(FrattiniSubgroup(G));
"C8 x C2"
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! I'll study this in detail.

Comment: You can also call `AssignGeneratorVariables(H);` and after that use `a` and `b` in relations instead of `H.1` and `H.2` (see [here](https://www.gap-system.org/Manuals/doc/ref/chap37.html#X814203E281F3272E)).

Comment: A slightly more slick way of constructing $G$ form $H$ is to use `ParseRelators`: `G:=H/ParseRelators(H,"a16,b4=a8,[a,b]=A2");`